# How to prevent Android OS from closing my React Native share extension when navigating away?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, share-extension

My React Native Android app extension automatically closes whenever I navigate away from the app (go to homepage, switch apps). This behavior isn't present on iOS so I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the native Android code that I have.

Anyone who is familiar with developing in Android know how to solve this?

I've looked into savedInstanceState and I've included it in my onCreate method in my Activity file but I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it correctly and/or if I need to add something else.

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;


public class ShareActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        // this is the name AppRegistry will use to launch the Share View
        return "Test";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

The logcat displays something about a sessionId not being persisted and a win.mRemoveonExit=true but there isn't any documentation on these messages.

```
5205-5448/? E/CustomizedTextParser: getCustomizedText Rule is empty. mRuleMap={}
10935-11009/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[48094197094119864] not persisted.
1262-5461/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{8f906be u0 com.factrmobile/com.factrmobile.share.ShareActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:870 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:851 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5366 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.onAnimationFinished:2403 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.setVisibility:551 
5205-5205/? E/OverviewCommandHelper: No closing app
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "share extention"?  Do you mean some graphical component of your app?  Is your activity being killed?  If so, in a normal app the answer would be to implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but given RN's threading model and the requirement for those to be synchronous I don't think you can actually do that.

Comment: @GabeSechan For example, when you want to share a URL or a photo, you click on the "Share" button and your application shows up as an option. That's what I meant by share extension.

Comment: Ok, so a UI element.  Most likely your Activity is getting killed.  In an actual native app, this wouldn't be an issue as the chooser is its own activity.  Or you coudl implement onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState.  But since all calls to javascript are asynchronous in RN, that solution won't work.  I don't know if you can fix this in RN, short of implementing a homebuilt save/restore mechanism by serializing your javascript state to disk.  I'd recommend living with this difference over that.  Or writing actual native code so you get all these nice OS features.

Comment: @GabeSechan but what's curious is that my MainActivity doesn't get killed in those same situations - only my ShareActivity aka the share extension.

Comment: @GabeSechan I found the issue... in my AndroidManifest.xml my android:noHistory attribute was set to "True". Either way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever runs into this issue, check your AndroidManifest.xml and look where you define your activity. Make sure you do not have `android:noHistory="true"`. Default value is false so leave it as is.